# Chained Payment using - ICEPAY payment gateway

Tags: php, payment

The concept to develop is similar to adaptive payment (in paypal).  But the thing is using icepay payment gateway (with ideal) for Netherlands.  (Using PHP)

I like to know whether it is possible to do so.   I tried analyzing the official links and websites but no luck.

Flow for your reference.

1. Customer -> Merchant (OK >Payment)
2. Merchant -> Customer (OK >Refund)
3. Merchant -> Suppliers. (**> Is this possible**)

What to make sure where it is possible or not.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Comment: I tried and didnt find a solution, so want to make sure whether it can be done or not.   I don't have the sample code for the "3rd" point that's why asked it as a question.  If you have any links for documentation can u please share here..  else it's ok thanks for your time.